# How do I install Ubuntu with full disk encryption on multiple drives?

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption, lvm

I want to install Ubuntu with full disk encryption using LVM but split over multiple drives.

For example, if I wanted everyting on /dev/sda except /var which went to /dev/sdb ? I can see how to do this without LVM by editing the partitions using the 'something else' option

From the installer it seems I can only install to a single drive when selecting LVM. Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installer does not support this scenario, so you'll have to do it manually.

There are many approaches that you can go with, and because you want `/var` explicitly to be on a separate physical volume, here's what I would do:

- First of all, install Ubuntu using the installer on the first physical volume (sda) with LUKS encryption and LVM, and later add the second volume. This will install `/var` on your drive, which you don't want to, but this is only temporary.
- Then set up LUKS on your second physical volume (sdb). You can either use a passphrase:

  ```
  cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb1 # Assuming that sdb1 is the partition where
                                  # you want to create the LUKS container.
                                  # You can also use your entire drive (/dev/sdb)
                                  # and have no partition table.
  ```
- Open the LUKS container that you just created:

  ```
  cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 lvm-var
  ```

  Now if you check `dmsetup` you should see two LUKS containers: one that was created during the Ubuntu installation (let's call it `lvm-ubuntu` for simplicity, though the name will be different), and one that we just created:

  ```
  $ dmsetup ls --target=crypt
  lvm-ubuntu ...
  lvm-var    ...
  ```
- Initialize the LUKS container for use with LVM:

  ```
  pvcreate /dev/mapper/lvm-var
  ```

  Now if you type `pvs` you should see two LVM physical volumes: the one where you installed Ubuntu and the new physical volume `lvm-var`:

  ```
  $ pvs
    PV                     VG         Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree   
    /dev/mapper/lvm-ubuntu ubuntu-vg  lvm2 ...  ...      ...
    /dev/mapper/lvm-var               lvm2 ...  ...      ...
  ```
- Create a new LVM volume group inside our new LVM physical volume:

  ```
  vgcreate var-vg /dev/mapper/lvm-var
  ```

  Now `vgs` should list it alongside the volume group create during installation:

  ```
  $ vgs
    VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree   
    ubuntu-vg    1   1 ...
    var-vg       1   0 ...
  ```
- Create a new LVM logical volume inside the group:

  ```
  lvcreate -L<size> -n var var-vg # Choose a size for your volume group. You can
                                  # specify 100%, but I always recommend using a
                                  # fraction of the available space, because you
                                  # can always grow logical volumes and
                                  # filesystems online, but shrinking it is a
                                  # pain.
  ```

  And `lvs` should reflect our changes:

  ```
    LV   VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
    root ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- ...
    var  var-vg    -wi-a----- ...
  ```
- Initialize an ext4 filesystem on that logical volume (or whatever filesystem type you prefer):

  ```
  mkfs.ext4 /dev/var-vg/var
  ```

  Confirm that the filesystem was created with `lsblk`.
- Almost there! Now we need to tell Ubuntu to open mount the LUKS container and filesystem automatically on boot. In order to do that:

  - Add this line to `/etc/crypttab`:

    ```
    var-vg UUID=<uuid of /dev/sdb1> none luks,discard,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
    ```

    You can get the UUID with `lsblk -f`. The `keyscript=decrypt_keyctl` is there so that you don't have to enter the same phassphrase twice on boot (in case your two LUKS containers are using the same phassprase).
  - Add this line to `/etc/fstab`:

    ```
    /dev/var-vg/var /var ext4 defaults 0 1
    ```

You're done! Now you can copy all the files from the `/var` on the first drive to the new logical volume on the second drive.